# android give name to bitmap and save it

Tags: android, string, bitmap, save

I have a bitmap that I want to save to the sd card. I have 2 problems with that:

1. Set a name to the saved file
2. Save the file

I looked around Stack Overflow and couldn't find anything that worked, for both problems (mostly for the saving part, the set name part just got me all confused)

Is there a simple straight forward solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap yourBitmap; // you have to get your bitmap into this variable
String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/"; // some times it may be only /sdcard not /mnt/sdcard
filePath += "newFileName.jpg";

        try {
            yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You have to use below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: before <application> or after </application>

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS it worked!!!! it was /sd_card and not /mnt/sd_card Thank you so much!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/pic.jpg"));
yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 80, out);
out.close();
```